# How to make an image change into others on click?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick, slideshow

I'm trying to make a sort of a minimal clickable "slideshow". So far I have only managed to make the image change into another. but I want to add other images to it. I tried to add other ifs and elses on the javascript but it doesn't work. (I'm a noob...) How can I do it? I juts want to click and the images change. This is my code so far:

```
<div> <img alt="" src="1.jpg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"/> </div>



<script language="javascript">
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "1.jpg") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "2.jpg";

        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "3.jpg";
    }

 }
</script>
```

thank you!

Comment: When comparing values you have to use == or === (in your if statement). Also, in the code block you're setting the source twice to different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cycle through those images, I'd make an array and swap the position of the elements in it like:

```
var imgs = ["2.jpg", "3.jpg", "1.jpg"];
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = imgs[0];
    imgs.push(imgs.shift())
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qydx6b2m/)**

Answer (score 3):

In your condition you need a double equals `==` - you can also pass `this` in to avoid `getElementById` multiple times. If you want to make a cycler - you can put your sources into an array and cycle thru that:

```
<img alt="" src="1.jpg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage(this)"/>

var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];
function changeImage(img) {
    var currentIndex = images.indexOf(img.src);
    var zeroBasedLength = images.length - 1;

    if (currentIndex == zeroBasedLength)
        img.src = images[0];
    else
        img.src = images[++currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to cycle through the images. Doesn't make such sense to change it twice inside one if statement.

Comment: Made an edit - setup an array of possible image choices and you can cycle through the array.

Comment: It doesn't work :( now when I click it does nothing... maybe I misunderstood something. this is what I have: 


    <div> <img style="width:50%" alt="" src="1.jpg"     id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage(this)"/> </div>



<script language="javascript">

      var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];
    function changeImage(this) {
    var currentIndex = images.indexOf(img.src);
    var zeroBasedLength = images.length - 1;

    if (currentIndex == zeroBasedLength)
        img.src = images[0];
    else
        img.src = images[++currentIndex];
}

    }
</script>